# 502 error on Websockets requests in private Cloud9 workspace

Tags: websocket, cloud9-ide, cloud9

Pointing our websocket client at our production servers works fine, but gets a 502 error when connecting to the dev environment on Cloud9.

Tried connecting to:

```
https://host.c9users.io:443
http://host.c9users.io:8080
http://host.c9users.io:80
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with private workspaces where the websockets request will be presented with the login screen and return a 502. An easy way to fix this:

**Go to ‘Share’ and make your application public (your code is still private)…**

[image]

Alternatively one of the support folks gave me this suggestion, although I never tried it:

If you have to initiate this with a GET request, try doing the following to the headers in the call:

- remove Mozilla and AppleWebKit strings from user-agent
- add Headless or PhantomJS to user-agent
- add cookie c9.live.user.click-through = ok
- add origin, postman-token, or x-request-id header to the request